# How do I display only part of a webpage with Android webview?

Tags: android, html, webview

I am not having trouble actually displaying the part of the webpage I want, but having buttons work.  The login button does not work AT ALL!

Here is my messy code.  I'd be happy if anyone can tell me what is happening.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();

int reloadCount = 0;
boolean reload = true;
String CurURL = "";
String Html = " ";

/**
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openMistar();
}

public void openMistar() {

    WebView Mistar = new WebView(this);
    setTitle("Student Connection");
    setVisible(true);
    Mistar.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    setContentView(Mistar);
    Mistar.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    Mistar.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    Mistar.loadUrl("https://zangleweb.resa.net/Woodhaven/Studentconnect/");
    Mistar.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onScaleChanged(WebView view, float oldScale, float newScale) {
            Log.w("Scale", "Scale changed");
            reload = false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            CurURL = view.getUrl();

            if (CurURL != null) {
                if (CurURL.equals("https://sisweb.resa.net/StudentPortal/Home/PortalMainPage")) {
                    view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

                    if (reload) {
                        view.reload();
                        reload = false;
                    }

                    Log.i("WebView", "Logged In");

                }
                if (CurURL.equals("https://sisweb.resa.net/StudentPortal/")) {

                    try {
                        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://zangleweb.resa.net/Woodhaven/Studentconnect/").get();
                        Elements newsRawTag = doc.select("#loginform");
                        String newPage = newsRawTag.html();
                        Log.i("HTML", "content: " + doc);
                        TagNode tagNode = new HtmlCleaner(props).clean(newPage);
                        SimpleHtmlSerializer htmlSerializer = new SimpleHtmlSerializer(props);
                        view.loadData(htmlSerializer.getAsString(tagNode),
                                "text/html", "utf-8");
                    } catch (IOException ex) {

                    }
                    view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
                    view.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);

                }
            }
        }

    });


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The login button on that website is bound to a jquery call on Document ready.
You need to make sure you are downloading document ready scripts at the bottom of the html as well as the jquery.form.js - which is used for checking the form feilds.